# How fast can you feasibly speed up blocktime?

Tags: substrate-node-template

I’d like to see if I can speed up block time rapidly with empty blocks to get to a target block number, before slow block time to 6 seconds. How fast could I feasibly go? Can I do 10 blocks per second, or is there a limit?

And are there considerations with BABE vs AURA? Is it easier with Aura so I can use just one node making selection trivial?

Comment: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/monthly-2021-09+1/frame_system/limits/struct.BlockWeights.html

I’m assuming I can squeeze as low as the base_block weight. I wonder how fast that is. Can I do more than 1 block per second?

Comment: To accurately answer this question, we need more context for your benchmark:

- how many nodes in the network?
- what is the geographical situation of these nodes?
- what is the hardware?
- what is the initial config?
...

I recommend you to read the answer of this question similar to yours:

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/what-is-the-possible-minimum-block-time

Comment: If you centralize the consensus or use specialized hardware, you could get very fast block times otherwise you will find a limit with low-level networking and power - but then you are giving up decentralization. What would be the advantage of faster block times? Maybe solve the problem elsewhere on the blockchain layer/stack? e.g. batching, intermediate caching layer